# App crash whenever I click 3 buttons given (Red, Yellow, Green)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setListeners()
    }

    private fun setListeners() {
        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(
                findViewById(R.id.red_button),
                findViewById(R.id.yellow_button),
                findViewById(R.id.green_button)
            )
        for (item in clickableViews) {
            item.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it)}
        }
    }
        private fun makeColored(view: View) {
            when (view.id) {
               R.id.red_button -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.box_three_text).setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_red)
                R.id.yellow_button -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.box_four_text).setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_yellow)
                R.id.green_button -> findViewById<Button>(R.id.box_five_text).setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_green)
                else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }
}
```

So Buttons in this program change the background of textView, but the app crashes whenever I click the button. Above is the complete code of MainActivity.

Comment: Add Crash Log for better understanding.